# How do we capitalize a hyphenated adjective which starts with an abbrevation in the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: hyphens, abbreviations, capitalization

I am really confused right now and I can't seem to find a straight answer to this question.

I was writing an essay and I am stumped on the correct capitalization when it came to starting a sentence with an abbreviation that is hyphenated. For example:

CT-guided treatment....
or
CT-Guided treatment...

Comment: As the hyphenated word starts with a capital letter anyway, I see no reason to capitalise the second element.

Comment: If you are not using a style guide, you should pick one and stick to it. There usually aren’t just one set of rules everyone uses for these sorts of things. A style guide will help you be consistent with others using the same style guide.

Comment: @Michael you saw `Ct-guided` with **only** the "C" capitalized? I would have thought both the "C" and the "T" should have been, as each letter refers to a separate word. (I know the BBC, notably, does not follow this, for example writing "Nasa" instead of "NASA.")

Comment: @randomhead - my typo.  I have seen (just now) 'CT-Guided' in the title of an article, and 'CT-guided' starting a sentence in the same article. This seems to agree with the Chicago Manual of Style, APA, etc.